# react where to put the firebase change listener in a component

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and am trying to link in a firebase-database. If I put the following in a render function:

```
let temperature = itemsRef.child('current_temperature');
temperature.on("value", function (snapshot) {
          myData = snapshot.val();
          console.log('temp', myData);
});
```

the log messages display in the console, but I can't see how to display this in the template. Is there a simple example component of how to get the updated values from this watcher to display in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code to `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook and in the place of console.log use binded `this.setState()`

```
componentDidMount() {
  let temperature = itemsRef.child('current_temperature');
  temperature.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    myData = snapshot.val();
    this.setState({
      temp: myData
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this soon. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks. This worked very well. I access the value with {this.myData}, which worked fine and I wasn't clear how to access 'temp'